# Connect tables with a specific role

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have **3** roles in my application visitor , individual , facility , and 4 services with table for each one that takes the id of the user

```
   - Visitor:-  will have no services
   - Individual:-  will have 2 services
   - Facility:-  will have 3 services
```

I want to connect the roles with the services tables so that each role can only connect to the table with the service it can provide ....  How can I map this with ASP Identity and SQL Server ?

Comment: Do you mean you want the table design for achieving this?

Comment: Yes, that can be achieved with asp identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This design

[image: Design]

I'm adding some sample records below with the given structure

[image: Sample]

Here there are 3 users and 4 roles.

UserId 2 (Individual) has got 2 roles

- RoleId 2 : Admin
- RolesId 3 : Normal User

UserId 3 (Facility) has got 3 roles

- RoleId 1 : Super Admin
- RoleId 2 : Admin
- RoleId 3 : Normal User

the below query can be used to retrieve the user roles

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM Users U 
INNER JOIN UserRoles UR 
  ON U.UserId = UR.UserId
INNER JOIN Roles R
  ON R.RoleId = UR.RoleId
WHERE ISNULL(Ur.ActFl,0)=1--1 : For Active Roles, 0 - For Inactive Roles
```